# Raspberry Pi with multiple arduinos using spi

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, raspberrypi

I want to use Raspberry Pi as an aggregator & distributor of messages originating from or destined for a flight simulation program.

I'd like to use arduinos connected via spi as specific hardware controllers, communicating as fast as possible with the raspberry pi to accept messages as they come from the simulation program and at the same time to transmit messages to the simulator when various switches and controls are operated.  At the same time, each arduino might need to control additional spi devices by acting as master, when not operating in slave mode to the raspberry pi.

Can several Arduinos be connected to a Raspberry Pi as a slave devices while acting as a master device for other devices connected to the arduino like an adc, a dac, a multiplexer or motor controller?

Comment: yes ...........

Comment: Personally I'd use the USB connections... much simpler.

Comment: Yes it can be done but it is not to common. It will be a nightmare with the chip selects. The SPI was designed as a local high speed bus for use on a PCB, not communication between modules. This link will help explain what I am trying to say: http://www.eeherald.com/section/design-guide/esmod12.html Remember you will have to use a level translator for the Pi.